# Emulator-x86.exe has stopped working in android studio

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

I created some Android apps with Android studio on one computer and they worked perfectly, but when I try to use Android Studio on my new computer, I can't even start the emulator. when I click *run in AVD manager*, the emulator doesnt even start and then the error message `Emulator-x86.exe has stopped working in Android studio` is showing up like this

[image: The error message please check it]

The *intel haxm* is running, I check it with `sc query intelhaxm` in   the command prompt. I'm using Nexus 5 setting with 512mb ram. I don't know what's happening, as the Android studio log is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Use Host GPU under Emulated Performance for AVD you are trying to start. Worked for me